# Return promise of foreach loop Q.JS

Tags: jquery, promise, q

I have below code which returns unexpected output using 'Q.js`and`Promise`. According to function it should return sum of all characters.

Expected output should be 16. (all characters of Apple, Banana and Grapes: 16)

```
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Grapes'];

var longProcess = function()
{
        var sum = 0;

    _.forEach(fruits, function(fruit){
        setTimeout(function(){
          sum = sum + fruit.length;
        }, 3000);
    });

   return sum
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        longProcess().then(function(data) {console.log(data);})
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzkngd5o/4/) here

Comment: You're pushing a function to the array name `promises`, that's really not what you want. Where did you try to create a promise?

Comment: Never use `forEach`. Always use `for … of` or `map`.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry. my bad. I have updated the Fiddle. Can you suggest me how can I achieve this using `Q.js`

Comment: Should the timeouts run concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: it should concurrently

Comment: Then use `Q.all`, `_.map` (instead of `forEach`) and `Q.delay` (instead of `setTimeout`).